# Job dispatched to default queue instead of assigned queue

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-8

Some of the jobs I have are being found in the default queue instead of the queue they are supposed to be in.

Here is the constructor for one such job:

```
public function __construct(Order $order)
{
    $this->onQueue('billing');
    $this->order = $order;
}
```

There is nowhere in the code where the queue value is changed.

```
dispatch(new DoBilling($order));
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this happens it can be one of the reasons. Which is all related to dev ops and server setups.

- Old servers or old code, pushing jobs on the queue, with code that does not comply with the example you provided.
- If the job is spawned from another job, ensure this queue has been restarted and up to date with the newest version of the code.
- Old jobs being processed with the wrong on queue settings and you are unaware of the queue having jobs waiting.

As a war time story, had a case of having to merge 3 queues into a single. There where some changes to the job properties. Where we kept getting errors about properties not being there, no matter how the job was created it should be. Turns out, our queue had a huge queue of old jobs built up and took multiple days to get the old jobs processed, to let the new jobs through with the proper properties.